# TypeScript definitions for various libraries and different versions - Typings, DefinitelyTyped

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, definitelytyped, tsd

Both `DefinitelyTyped` and `typings` allow us to use existing JS libraries along with their TypeScript bindings (definitions, .d.ts) provided by the community. My question is - *does any of these platform provide a possibility to use a binding for a **certain version** of a certain library*?

For example, I can see in [DefinitelyTyped/jQuery](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts), that it supports only this:

```
// Type definitions for jQuery 1.10.x / 2.0.x
```

and this is the only file. And jQuery seems to be pretty popular library. So I expect that support for other libraries would be even worse.

Anyway, are the TS bindings still so immature that they don't allow to specify target version of a given library? Is this feature planned to be added?

Comment: The [typings page on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings) shows how to get specific versions (within the Quick Start section, find the comment `# Search and install by version. `).