# DefinitelyTyped vs typings - comparison

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, definitelytyped

Could someone clearly state the differences between `DefinitelyTyped` and `typings`? Both provide TS definitions for existing JS libraries, but I'm unsure about the differences.

Comment: DefinitelyTyped is just a location of .d.ts files. Typings is a utility that retrieves those definitions.

Comment: What exactly is in this question that couldn't be answered in the other question you asked moments earlier? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297746/typescript-definitions-for-various-libraries-and-different-versions-typings-d

Comment: @Claies oh that's easy - this I just ask about something different :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Mike said, `typings` is a utility used to pull in type definitions (the `d.ts` files).  DefinitelyTyped is a repository for those typings, along with NPM and [these](https://github.com/typings/typings#sources) other repositories/sources.